# Why Does Blues Have the first 4 Bars on the I chord?

Tags: guitar, chord-progressions, blues, musical-forms

Why is it so common to hold the I Chord for 4 bars?

See other variations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-bar_blues

Comment: There’s some blues where the same chord is used for the entire song. E.g., “Who Do You Love” by Bo Diddly.

Comment: Many blues progressions go to the IV chord for bar 2 then back to I for bars 3&4.

Comment: There's a lot more detail from cognitive science and music theory, but essentially it's because that's how long it takes for us to get familiar with it and be ready to hear the IV.

Comment: Because if it didn't, it wouldn't be a blues. Having got that out of the way, consider something more interesting. It doesn't sit on I for four bars, but on I7. A dominant 7th shape. Then to IV7, another dominant 7th shape. Then V7, IV7 again and home to I7. Only one of those dom7-type chords does what a dom7 OUGHT to do, resolve down a 5th/up a 4th. And that chord - the first one in the sequence, ought to be establishing the tonic, not immediately pulling away from it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where the question is probably more interesting than the answer. The answer, loosely speaking, amounts to "because that's just how it is." A similar question that comes to mind is "why is blues so often twelve bars?"

That said, being a folk form, blues, like much folk music, adheres to fairly simple chords and form — so it's playable by "regular folk". As the form developed and musicians began to experiment with it, it developed increasingly sophisticated variations.

Comment: I just like to guess: the origin may be the work song (antiphonal) with soloist (precantor) and choir.

Comment: How does that fit in with a 12-bar blues form?

Comment: @LaurencePayne Please say more about what you're asking.

Comment: There is ab 8 bar blues that is very common.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably more useful to reverse things, asking why it's got any harmonic variation at all. I mean, many times in modern music, you hold on one or two chords so that whatever is important at that time can do what it wants. You can reference modal jazz like *A Love Supreme*, but I'm thinking that metal riffage is sitting on one chord, and John Lee Hooker songs like "Boogie Chillun" work like that.

Then, as presented by [Bob Brozman](http://www.bobbrozman.com/tip_evol12bar.html), you start getting the V, then the IV, jazz, swing, sevenths everywhere, etc. You do see increasing harmonic complexity, but then, the changes start being an obstacle course and sometimes you just need to do a floor routine.

Comment: In harder variants of heavy metal (I'd say harder than power metal and neoclassical metal; I recall this tendency in progressive metal and the extreme metal sub-genres), I actually often hear metal riffs as changing chords on *every note*, including at chromatic neighbour tones. Those riffs therefore change chords *several times per measure*.

Comment: I don't know if those filler notes are chord changes. Think of 'Enter Sandman', isn't that whole riff in E the whole time? Same with the 'Master of Puppets' riff.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, I'd have to listen and think about that. I know there _is_ music like that; my extreme jazz example is "Giant Steps" (which Coltrane recorded within a month of the modal _Kind Of Blue_ sessions). Sometimes the challenge is treating the changes like an obstacle course, showing you won't fall off, but sometimes it's a wide and flat and open space, like a gymnastics floor routine, where the challenge is how far you can push yourself.

Comment: @CoolGuy - Those metal riffs I was referring to change power chords *on every note*.

Comment: Isn't that similar to a guitar solo, the solo hits several notes while it is still 1 bar in 1 key?  And also 5ths (power chords) aren't chords since they're only 2 notes.    Also, Master of Puppets changes power cords every note.

Comment: It seems like that might be melody, similar to a classical guitarist finger picking through a scale with double stops while holding on chord.

Comment: Guys? "Other music behaves differently" is fine and true but really has nothing to do with how blues changes evolved.

Comment: Talking about "chord" changes on every note in a guitar riff of solo doesn't make sense. At the very least it seems to miss the concept of passing tones. But more importantly in some styles "chord" and harmonic progression are not useful ideas. Sometimes tonic, mode, and rhythm... not chords in harmonic progression ...are the main elements. Or you can see a combination. Rock often will have riff based sections contrasting with progression based stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it so common to hold the I Chord for 4 bars?

You give a link to variations on the blue chord progression, so obviously you know that the blues does not necessarily start with four bars on the tonic.

Maybe your question is "why hold the tonic for so long?" Or something like that.

Many blues songs are just riffs that repeat over all three chords `I IV V`. Sometimes people say you can play the blues scale over any chord in the progression. In a way, you could say there isn't any need to change chords in the blues, not in the traditional sense of matching the tones of chord and melody. In a more "traditional" song the chords change to support/match the melody, but in the blues you don't really need to do that.

Many blues will play the tonic for four bars, because there isn't a reason to do otherwise.

If you want a blues that is direct and unpretentious, dispense with dressing up the progression with fancy changes.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of music relies on repetition - of notes, and of timings. There's a lot of Blues that uses a two bar phrase that gets repeated. Playing over the same two bars worth of chords, and repeating necessitates four bars of that same chord - generally I. Then continuing the process, the same phrase (two bars again) can be repeated, but a 4th higher over the IV chord. Again, repetition comes to the fore, and the original phrase can be re-played over bars 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's really about grounding.  In any pattern, you need to set a base from which to jump.  4 bars is just a really good way to do that musically.  It's like saying "this is where we are starting from.  This is home!"  Then we hit IV and then back to I, reinforcing it.  Once we have adequately established this grounding, then we can play around with more complex progressions and, generally, the listener will know that we will end up back home again.